# Making a connection to Qemu using Libvirt Java API

Tags: java, swing, qemu, libvirt

Problem statement:

1. Create a connection to Qemu. Done by the call-conn1 = new Connect("qemu+ssh://login_name@IP/system", false). This is done in one class (connect.java).
2. Create new VMs on the above machine at the IP. Done by the function call create() in ANOTHER class (create.java)

Doubt:
1. When I run the above program, every time I want to create a VM, I have to create an object of connect.java . Is there any way I could make just ONE connection to Qemu and proceed with my operations (create.suspend) on the VMs running on it? I'm using Swing to create the UI everytime the user wants to create/suspend a VM.

Comment: I cannot give an answer regarding whether or not you need to create a new "connect.java" object since I'm not familiar with that class, but I can say that there should be no need to create a new Swing GUI object if it is coded correctly. Having said that, I don't see how Swing really ties in with your main problem.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Thanks! I got the answer to my question. I'll post the code once I've tested it!

Comment: great. I will look forward to your reply.

Comment: @P Ramesh: did you have success? Any code to show?

Comment: @kanaka- Hey, I've updated my answer below. since my code is a part of a large project, I've refrained from posting the code per se but I've explained the method below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do to solve this was to create a Global connect variable which connected to the KVM/Xen Hypervisor and pass it to the Swing application I was calling inside this class. One important thing which I'd found out was by default, only 20 connections could ba made to any hypervisor using Libvirt. hence the global variable.